# How do I push a commit without destroying teammate work?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-pull

I'm new to Git and the problem I had today at my uni project is the following:

- I did some changes to certain files, commited and pushed to our GitHub repo.
- I told my teammate that I did the commit and he complained that now he can't commit his changes.

I didn't realize that he was coding at the same time as me -- he says that if he pulls my commit then his changes to the same files would be lost.

What do we do now, do I just tell him to copy those files to another place in his drive and then "combine" the changes? How do we avoid this situation in the future?

Sorry for the poor wording and stuff, as I said I'm a beginner and very clueless about this topic.

Comment: 1. git can merge pretty well 2. you could work on different branches and do pull requests.

Comment: Do consider looking into branching and merging, and how that functions in your specific environment.  That's the best place to start.  Right now, this is a bit too broad, without specific context as to whether you were both working in the same area of code or not.

Comment: How do you avoid this?  Talk first. :-)  That said, sometimes it happens, even in real teams who do talk.  Git will not lose his changes (at least not purposefully), instead a `git pull` will likely result in a merge conflict.  While they can be stressful (because folks don't deal with them often), there are ways to back out and try again without losing work.  In the future, branching and merging is a better way to go.  You might find this a helpful introduction: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts

Comment: As @JohnSzakmeister mentions, changes won't be lost. Maybe he hasn't committed his changes and git is telling him to stash or commit them before proceeding. This is exactly what git/version control does well. Merge conflicts are unavoidable, but don't be affraid of them.

Comment: "he says that if he pulls my commit then his changes to the same files would be lost." It's not true, he will encounter conflict, and then you two guys need to resolve it together, since you two guys make the conflict. From my experience, I will always avoid conflict before it happens. You need to predict the files you modify will not affect your teammate, and negotiate with him to avoid modify the same file at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't realize that he was coding at the same time as me

Welcome to the real world of programming. This happens **all** the time.

It is such a common problem that any decent version control system has built-in capabilities to **merge** changes automatically. Git is extremely powerful about that, when the changes are in different parts of a file, the second person doing a pull (or fetch/rebase) won't even notice. You only notice when git is unable to merge itself, then you end up with merge conflicts, which require human attention.

> What do we do now,

Let's assume your coworker did a `git pull` that fails because you pushed changes affecting some of this files. Each file will now **contain** the information about conflicting updates. Decent editors like Visual Studio code will **show** you all these conflicts, and allow you to pick this or that version of the corresponding code. Turn to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol), and read the section about "Merge conflicts".

In other words, the real answer is: it is time for **all** of the people working with you to pick up a good book about git (like this [one](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)) and start *learning* about the tool you are using. You see, git is an extremely powerful, and sometimes confusing tool. If you are serious about learning programming, then you have to be serious about learning such tools as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this really nice answer! I'll start reading about merging and branches then. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You and your teammate can have different branch using same repository.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b 'yourBranch' #this branch for you

git checkout master
git checkout -b 'aliceBranch' #this branch for your friend

# when your done, push to related branch
git push origin <branchName>
```

[git-scm.com/docs](https://git-scm.com/docs)